# Sequencing in Teradata

Tags: sql, sequence, teradata

I would like to create a SELECT query that results in a view that is 30 fields long and 1 record thick. 2 records if we're counting the title.

The specific part of the larger query in question is:

```
WHERE CAST(EVENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE) - CONTRACT_EFFECTIVE_DATE = 1
```

This produces the results desired - records where the days between EVENT_TIMESTAMP and CONTRACT_EFFECTIVE_DATE is 1.

But I'd like this for 30 days. Something like:

```
WHERE CAST(EVENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE) - CONTRACT_EFFECTIVE_DATE = 1:30
```

Is that possible? I could just cut n paste the query 30 times and change the number 1 to the corresponding value. But surely there is a better way?

The results would look something like:

```
1 day   2 day   3 day   4 day
10       11       8      14
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's another PIVOT query, lots of cut&paste again.

Assuming you want to count the number of rows matching each day range:

```
SELECT 
   COUNT(CASE WHEN CAST(EVENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE) - CONTRACT_EFFECTIVE_DATE = 1 THEN 1 END) AS "1 day",
   COUNT(CASE WHEN CAST(EVENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE) - CONTRACT_EFFECTIVE_DATE = 2 THEN 1 END) AS "2 day",
   COUNT(CASE WHEN CAST(EVENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE) - CONTRACT_EFFECTIVE_DATE = 3 THEN 1 END) AS "3 day",
   COUNT(CASE WHEN CAST(EVENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE) - CONTRACT_EFFECTIVE_DATE = 4 THEN 1 END) AS "4 day",
...
FROM tab
WHERE CAST(EVENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE) - CONTRACT_EFFECTIVE_DATE <= 30
```

You could also put the calculation in a Derived Table, but this just *looks* simpler:

```
SELECT 
   COUNT(CASE WHEN diff = 1 THEN 1 END) AS "1 day",
   COUNT(CASE WHEN diff = 2 THEN 1 END) AS "2 day",
   COUNT(CASE WHEN diff = 3 THEN 1 END) AS "3 day",
   COUNT(CASE WHEN diff = 4 THEN 1 END) AS "4 day"
FROM 
 (
   SELECT CAST(EVENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE) - CONTRACT_EFFECTIVE_DATE AS diff
   FROM tab
   WHERE diff <= 30
 ) AS dt
```

Comment: Thank you again @dnoeth. This is really helpful. So, the query I have just done is called a PIVOT query? Or it's a case of if a PIVOT query was an option in this version of TD?

Comment: PIVOT is a generic name, you pivot a vertical to a horizontal result set, some DBMSes support it directly, but not Teradata :-(

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this?

```
WHERE CAST(EVENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE) - CONTRACT_EFFECTIVE_DATE BETWEEN 1 AND 30
```

I think `BETWEEN` is what you want.

Comment: it looks like that has resulted in one cell of data that, I guess, is the summation of 1:30.
I need there to be 30 fields, which each field populated with the value resulting in what the query would give if the snippet above said, for example, 
WHERE CAST(EVENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE) - CONTRACT_EFFECTIVE_DATE = 3 
For 3 days difference.