# SELECT a sequence of numbers and then link to another query

Tags: sql, teradata

This question is on the back of one I asked recently:([Sequencing in Teradata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23527359/sequencing-in-teradata)).

If I use the following query to select a range of numbers from 1: 50:

```
WITH Nums(N) AS (
    SELECT N 
    FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY i) As N
    FROM RDMAVWSANDBOX.xref_integers T
    ) T
    WHERE N <51
    )
SELECT * FROM Nums
ORDER BY N
```

That produces the expected results: A query returns a 1 field wide 50 row long query result numbered 1: 50. (Xref_integers is a dummy table with 10K records).

But Now I want to integrate this with my actual work.

If I have a table called "People". Each record in People is an instance of a purchase of a cabbage.

So I want to know the count of people that have bought 1:50 cabbages.

So to integrate with the above - how would I do that?

I got stuck because I wanted to do two FROM statements:

SELECT * FROM NUMS and SELECT COUNT(People.C) FROM People.

If the field names in People are EMAIL there is just one field and where the count of emails is the count of cabbages that a person has bought, how can I say select the count of people who own N number of cabbages. So for each number in the range?

I know that I could just say `SELECT EMAIL, COUNT(EMAIL) FROM PEOPLE GROUP By EMAIL` in this example but if I had to compare to a discreet range of numbers - how would I do that?

Comment: Please edit your question and show sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff actually I'm going to spend some time on this and possibly redo the question altogether if I can't figure it out. I'm having a hard time getting my head around sequencing, and a few other concepts (partition/qualify) but gimme some time and I'll get it! Thanks for all your help so far (You've answered a few of my Qs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT * FROM Nums 
left join (SELECT EMAIL, COUNT(EMAIL) as nemail FROM PEOPLE GROUP By EMAIL) as x on 
nemail=n ORDER BY N
```

Comment: Thanks @neiha that produces the results I guess that I asked for but I now realise I need to work on this a bit more.